# spymemcached client : how to increase the speed of get method

Tags: memcached

I am working with spymemcached client and followed the following tutorial

http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/SpringIntegration

In the following code, I set 10 objects in the cache

```
  for (int i = 0; i <  10; i++) 
        memcache.set(Integer.toString(i), 86400, "this is a test " + i);
```

But when I am trying to retrieve them back with

```
   for (int i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
        memcache.get(Integer.toString(i));
```

To my surprise, it is taking quite a bit. I would like to know how I can optimize the speed of objects that I wanted to retrieve from cache.

I have also tried http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Examples but it did not help.

I have four boxes which I am utilizing as memcached servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bulkGet() function in order to send a request for multiple keys at once. There are also asyncGet and asyncBulkGet() calls that allow you to do these calls asynchronously. The asynchronous calls would help in cases where you can issue a get, do some other stuff, and then check the result of the get call.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I have tried all of them and yes they are working fine but here the situation is that I have a number of different types of object that I am caching and I don't have to retrieve them all at once. There are many conditions that are to be fulfilled before an object is retrieved. Therefore, get remains the only choice. I tried manipulating all the options in spymemcached like servers, protocol, transcoder etc to speed up the retrieval process but no success. Here I need a help, therefore to get them up quickly. Thanks

Comment: How long does it take? Also, it you issue a request for a single item and need it immediately then you will have to wait. You should be getting sub-millisecond responses though.

Comment: Here are some statistics - Time to add data = 11.830275ms
- Time to get data using get= 702.634553ms
- Time to get data using getBulk = 78.211337ms .... these are for 10 objects. So the time to retrieve a single object is roughly around 70.26 ms which is too much. Now here's one thing more, this is just a simple String object, my application utilizes a number of complex objects. Also would that matter if the objects are of different types then there retrieval time is also different (if that makes sense)? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's way too long. All of these requests should be sub-millisecond. I saw you made a comment on the Spymemcached page. Could you file a bug for this and in that bug post your full source? I can run through the code an take a look at it later. Also, try to provide as much information about your network setup in the bug report as possible.

Comment: I would do it but before that I would like to mention one thing that I haven't mentioned before and that is my spymemcached server resides in Washington and I am in Phoenix, Az. I access those servers using VPN connection. Could it be the reason that it is taking so long for object retrievel.

Comment: Yeah, that is likely the reason. The bulk of the latency you are seeing is from the network. Memcached is meant to be accessed by your application from inside the datacenter.

Comment: so is there any way that I can reduce this time? As I stated earlier that I tweaked almost all the properties of spymemcached but nothing really decreased the amount of time.

Comment: Your web application and memcached server should be inside the same network. I would recommend developing you application locally and then deploying it your web host in Washington. As I mentioned before the latency is from the network and there is nothing that either Spymemcached or memcached can do to make this latency lower.